# How to change Number of copies to print in asp.net

Tags: c#

hai frnds , how will change the number of copies to print in asp.net . I want default 4 print. On click i am using window.print method, its opening print dialog there we will change the number of copies instead of this by default it should print 4 copies.

Comment: You cannot control the print dialog out of asp.net

Comment: Is this any report or reporting tool like Crystal report?

Comment: You will be printing using the browser (like IE, Chrome), there is no way you can set this value from your webpage. If it was an desktop app you could have specified the number of copies.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing printing at the server, ASP.NET isn't doing the printing; the browser is. You can't control that from code, AFAIK. You would need to be using a plugin of some kind, *at a minimum*.